Postman validation_error
I have some interesting problem with my postman test.
At one point, an error with code 400 ruins everything, namely, with the requirement of variables - first_par and sec_par, but the system does not respond, even if I enter them manually inside the body.
regardless of the type of request, using PATCH or POST, the result is one - 400 and:
validation_errors: {…}
error_fields: {}
absent_fields: {…}
main: [2]
0: "first_par"
1: "sec_par"
i`ve tied smth like this. Data formats:  first_par - number, sec_par - mail:
{   "main": [{     "first_par": "{{first_par}}",     "sec_par": "{{sec_par}}"   }] }
Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

This is going to be down to the API specification and what it will accept.  Your guess looks sensible, but its just a guess.  Much better to get the API specification and work from that.  Hopefully it will explain how the body needs to look, and ideally if its a good API specification, it will also include examples.
